# What does it mean to say the homology of a pair is $H=\left( \mathbb{Z},1 \right)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, notation, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I encountered a definition which is unclear to me. When one says that the homology of $X$ is $H=\left( \mathbb{Z},1 \right)$ then I do not know what it means. I know what homology is but I do not understand what $H=\left( \mathbb{Z},1 \right)$ is.

Let $F$ be a real Banach space and $U$ a nonempty open subset. Assume $\Phi \in C^1\left(U,\mathbb{R}\right).$ Define $\Phi^d=\left\lbrace x \in E: f\left(x\right) \leq d \right\rbrace,$ then one can compute the Homology of the pair $\left( \Phi^d,\Phi^d \setminus \lbrace u_0\rbrace\right),$ $d=\Phi\left(u_0\right),$ and $u_0$ is a point of mountain pass type in the sense of Hofer. It turns out that $H=\left(\mathbb{Z},1 \right).$

These contents are contained on pages 309-310 of this paper: [HOFER, H. : A note on the topological degree at a critical point of mountainpath-type,
Proc . Amer. Math. Soc. 9 0 (1984), 309-315 .](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1984-090-02/S0002-9939-1984-0727256-0/)

Could you show me? thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: I only want to know what the $\left(\mathbb{Z},1\right)$ is

Comment: It states that the Homology $H$ of the pair $\left( \Phi^{d},\Phi^{d}\setminus\lbrace u_0 \rbrace \right)$ with $d=\Phi\left(u_0\right)$ and $\Phi \in C^1\left(U,\mathbb{R}\right).$

Comment: the reason I ask for context is that I've never seen this notation before.

Comment: can you clear me for this?

Comment: Could you provide a picture when this notation is used ?

Comment: You need to define the symbols you use.  I haven't the faintest idea what most of them mean.  What kind of homology?  Simplicial, singular, cellular...?  Is $X$ a topological space?  You say $\Phi$ is a $C^1$ function on $U$, but then you write $\Phi^d \setminus \{u_0\}$ (with $d = \Phi(u_0)$???), which makes absolutely no sense to me.  *Please explain your notation.*

Comment: $\Phi^d=\left\lbrace x \in E: f\left(x\right) \leq d \right\rbrace$

Comment: I have fixed the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a strange notation.  I have never seen anything like it before, but from context it seems that this means the homology is the graded abelian group whose only nonzero part is $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree $1$.  That is, "$H=(\mathbb{Z},1)$" means that $H_i(\Phi^d,\Phi^d \setminus \lbrace u_0\rbrace)=0$ for $i\neq 1$ and $H_1(\Phi^d,\Phi^d \setminus \lbrace u_0\rbrace)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: actually I haven't understood the notation of pair $\left( \Phi^d,\Phi^d \setminus \lbrace u_0\rbrace \right)$ yet

Comment: This is just relative homology--do you know what that is?

Comment: can you show me a book which helps me?

Comment: I am a student and a beginner in this area! so I need some books of this area to read more... thank you

Comment: You can learn the basics of homology theory from many books, including pretty much any introductory algebraic topology textbook.  One such book is [Hatcher's _Algebraic Topology_](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html).